# OpenGL/Glut glutSolidCube()

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glut, cube

I was wondering how I would get the min and max vertices of a cube that has been drawn with

```
glutSolidSphere(1)
```

Note: I am using C++

Comment: Hi Cindy - let us know what you have tried so far.

Comment: Which function? It says `glutSolidCube()` in the title, and `glutSolidSphere()` in the body.

Answer (score 1):

`glutSolidSphere` is a function who's behavior is defined by GLUT. So you would look up how `glutSolidSphere` generates its vertices by [reading its documentation](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node81.html#SECTION000121000000000000000). From that page, we can see that, since you gave it a radius of 1, it will generate points within that radius, centered at the origin.